# typeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a problem in angularjs when i trying to execute this code it returns to me TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined.

Here is my code :
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"> 

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="services/app.js"></script>
<script src="services/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="services/common/services.js"></script>
<script src="services/oliveService.js"></script>

<title>Task Managment System</title>
</head>
<body ng-view>

</body>
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.services','myApp.controllers'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

   .when('',{
   })

   .when('/blah', {
     title: 'Blah',
     templateUrl : 'templates/blah.html'
   })
   .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'}); 
})

.directive('header', function () {
 return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/header.html",
    controller: "HeaderCtrl" 
 }
})
```

When i remove templateURl from the directive then it work fine but i need this directive content is called from the template.

**controller.js**

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('Header controller called');
    //$(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
})
```

when i am also comment jquery line it works. this is used for dropdown content in header

**header.html**

```
 <div>
     <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="call_page('account')">Setting</a></li>
     </ul>
     <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="brand-logo">Timetrack</a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">{{email | capitalize}}
                  <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
              </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
     </nav>
</div>
```

in the header.html there is plenty of code but here i am just print a some of them.
I need to apply this header directive in other pages like

**blah.html**

```
<div header></div>
<div>
    <h1> this is blah </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: remove extra `</body>` from your index.html first.

Comment: Put `$(".dropdown-button").dropdown()` in your `header` directive's `link` function. Template may be not ready when controller fires. AND, DOM operation is not recommended in controller.

Comment: can you show me how to put that in function as you said it will be helful @Yin Gang thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping @Yin Gang.